# Django User Registration AttributeError

Tags: python, django, registration

When attempting to register a custom built user class, which has a OneToOneField relationship with a django user class, an exception is raised, with no file or line # information.

```
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The django error page points this to the views.py line 'if form.is_valid(),' although I don't understand how this causes the exception listed.

my models.py user class:

```
""" User Model """
class ShedUser( models.Model ):
    """
    Class Name: ShedUser
    Attributes:
        user            - OneToOne relation with django User
        zipcode         - User's Zipcode
        community       - community related to user's zipcode
    """
    user                = models.OneToOneField( User )
    zipcode             = models.CharField( max_length = 5 )
    community           = models.ForeignKey( 'Community', related_name='community'  )

    # Returns user's username
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my views.py UserRegistration:

```
""" UserRegistration
to Register a new User account """
def UserRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm( request.POST )
        if form.is_valid():
            # empty initiated objects
            community = Community()
            sheduser = ShedUser()

            # Full community list
            communities = Community.objects.all()

            # Boolean for new user's community existence
            community_exists = False

            # Parse through existing communities to assign new user to a community
            for current_community in communities:
                # If the new user's zipcode matches an existing zipcode
                if current_community.zipcode == form.cleaned_data['zipcode']:
                    community = current_community
                    community_exists = True

            # If no community exists with this zipcode:
            if not community_exists:
                # Generate a new stat object for the new community
                new_stats = Stats( user_count=0, tool_count=0, machinery_count=0, electronic_count=0, borrow_count=0 )
                new_stats.save()
                # Create the new community
                community.zipcode       = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']
                community.stats         = new_stats
                community.save()

            # Create the django user object
            user                        = User.objects.create_user( username = form.cleaned_data['username'], email = form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'], first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'], last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'])
            user.save()

            # Create the ShedUser object
            sheduser.user                   = user
            sheduser.zipcode                = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']
            sheduser.community              = community
            sheduser.community.stats.user_count     += 1
            sheduser.community.save()
            sheduser.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
        else:
            return render_to_response('register.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('register.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and finally my forms.py :

```
""" UserRegistrationForm """
class UserRegistrationForm( ModelForm ):
    username            = forms.CharField( label=('User Name'))
    email               = forms.EmailField( label=('Email Address'))
    password            = forms.CharField( label=('Password'), widget = forms.PasswordInput( render_value=False ) )
    password1           = forms.CharField( label=('Verify Password'), widget = forms.PasswordInput( render_value=False ) )
    first_name          = forms.CharField( label=('First Name'))
    last_name           = forms.CharField( label=('Last Name'))

    class Meta:
        model = ShedUser
        exclude = ('user', 'community')

    # Clean the Username
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        # Ensure username doesn't exist
        try:
            User.objects.get( username=username )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError("That username is already taken.")

    # Clean the form passwords
    def clean(self):
        # verify passwords match
        password        = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password1       = self.cleaned_data['password1']

        if not password1:
                raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password!")
        if password != password1:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords did not match.")
        return password1
```

Full traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/

Django Version: 1.5.4
Python Version: 3.2.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
'models')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\ToolShare\R2\Code\Release-2\toolshare\models\views.py" in UserRegistration
  104.         if form.is_valid():
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  126.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _get_errors
  117.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  274.         self._post_clean()
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  317.         exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _get_validation_exclusions
  303.                 field_value = self.cleaned_data.get(field, None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /register/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Please let me know whether more code is required, or you need any more information.

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return the cleaned_data and not the password1 on the form validation.

your clean should look like the following:

```
def clean(self):
    # Runs the super methods clean data to validate the form (ensure required fields are filled out and not beyond max lens)
    cleaned_data = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).clean()
    # verify passwords match
    password        = cleaned_data['password']
    password1       = cleaned_data['password1']

    if not password1:
            # raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password!")
            # instead of raising exceptions you should put an error on the form itself.
            self._errors['password1'] = self.error_class(['you must confirm your password'])
    if password != password1:
            # raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords did not match.")
            # instead of raising exceptions you should put an error on the form itself.
            self._errors['password1'] = self.error_class(['Your passwords did not match'])
    return cleaned_data # return that cleaned data
```

### EDIT

I also want to add, you should absolutely de-couple the form from the models, i know you can tie them in together as you have, but you should separate that logic out into a separate controller.

Your form validations should be pretty lightweight, any additional validations should happen in a separate controller - it makes the code much more re-usable.

also, i can't remember, but i'm positive your additional clean method will never be called.  Stick that in the main `def clean` defition and separate calls out to obtain objects...etc into a User object controller.

Comment: Worked perfectly. and thank you for the tip on putting errors on the form. I'm rather new to django and there's a lot of different techniques I find myself mixing together, so it really helps to get clarification :)

Comment: @Zack just remember, exceptions are for truly exceptional cases.  Your user forgetting to confirm their password is not an exception worthy of spitting up a stack trace and raising an error.  Just prompt them to try again! The same goes for above where you do User.objects.get() and catch the error, User.objects.filter() will return an empty array and you can check the length.  Catching errors as means to determine application state is bad habit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get more used to using exceptions when actually necessary.

Comment: Oddly enough, after changing the functionality of my clean_username function to not use an exception, it broke the code. Putting the same code from clean_username in to the clean function made it work again. Although i need you to dumb-down your tip on decoupling the form from the models, cause I didn't really understand that.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon unfortunately you are completely mistaken about the use of exceptions here. They are absolutely the right way to go, they are the way Django has designed its validation process. In Python it is perfectly normal to use them for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think there are very legitimate reasons to use exceptions and django has allowed for multiple ways to handle form validation. Either via throwing exceptions or adding errors to specific fields. There are probably merits to both - but in general it is a good practice to keep exceptions to a min. Unless we're talking java :p TIL.