# Django: extend default user and django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

i have:
Django 1.9
django-registration 2.1

I want to extend default django user with "about me" field.

From docs suggested solution:
models.py:

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.TextField()
```

forms.py:

```
class RegisterForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExtendedUser
```

Result:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/register/
'ExtendedUser' object has no attribute 'set_password'
```

probably because ExtendedUser is not inherited from User.

What is the solution to this? Should i go [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716196/django-user-registration-attributeerror) way and override registration's default view or is there a better solution?